# How to hide or make visible panels from datalist_itemcommand

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, datalist

Spent pretty much the whole day one this and have scoured as many sites as I can find without help.

I have a panel on an asp.net page that is hidden until the user clicks a `linkbutton`. The panel contains a `DataList`. Here's the .aspx:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlManageYourGallery" Visible="false" runat="server">

    <div style="width:70%; height:90%; position:fixed; left:200px; top:10px; background-color:White; background-color:#f1f1f1 ">
        <center>
            <h1>Manage Your Gallery</h1></center>
        <div style="position:absolute; top:50px; left:25px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; height:90%; width:50%; background-color:white; overflow:auto;">

            <asp:DataList ID="dlManageGallery" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceManageGallery" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Flow" DataKeyField="RecNum">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div style="position:relative; background-color:#fafad2; padding:10px; margin:10px;  border: 5px solid #b0c4de; border-radius: 3px; width:90%;">
                        <p>Image No.
                            <%# Eval( "RecNum") %>&nbsp;Uploaded
                                <%# Eval( "UploadDate") %>
                        </p>
                        <center><img src='<%# Eval("ImageFilename") %>' width="50%" /></center>
                        <br /> Caption:
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtImageCaption" Width="400" Text='<%# Eval("Caption") %>' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <center>

                            <asp:Panel id="pnlImageControls" visible="true" runat="server">
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDeleteImage" CommandName="DeleteImage" Text="Delete this image" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkSaveImageChanges" CommandName="SaveChanges" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("RecNum") %>' Text="Save Changes" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
                            </asp:Panel>
                        </center>

                    </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:DataList>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceManageGallery" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyConnectionString2 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [RecNum], [ImageFilename], [Caption], [UploadDate] FROM [tblGallery] ORDER BY [RecNum] DESC">
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
        </div>
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlImageDeleteWarning" Visible="false" runat="server">
            <div style="position:fixed; left:600px; top:300px; background-color:White; border:5px solid red; padding:10px;">
                <center>
                    <p style="color:Red; font-weight:bold;">Are you sure you want to delete this image?</p>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnDeleteImage" CommandName="DeleteImageConfirm" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("RecNum") %>' Text="Yes, delete this image" runat="server" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <asp:Button ID="btnCancelDelete" CommandName="DoNotDelete" text="No, do not delete" runat="server" />
                </center>
            </div>
        </asp:Panel>

    </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

As can be seen, each data item in the DataList contains panels that contain other controls. What I need to do is, upon clicking the `lnkDeleteImages` link, the `pnlImageControls` panel should hide and the `pnlImageDeleteWarning` should show. Here's the codebehind for that:

```
Private Sub dlManageGallery_ItemCommand(source As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataListCommandEventArgs) Handles dlManageGallery.ItemCommand

    Dim pnlImageControls As Panel = CType(e.Item.FindControl("pnlImageControls"), Panel)

    Select Case e.CommandName
        Case "DeleteImage"
            pnlImageControls.Visible = False
            pnlImageDeleteWarning.Visible=True
    End Select

End Sub
```

Now, I've tried every variation of the `FindControl` method that I could find on the internet, and nothing has worked.

However, while debugging at a breakpoint, using `? pnlImageControls.visible` on the immediate window, it returns the value 'true' before the click, and 'false' after the click. The control thinks it's invisible, but it's not.

I've even tried -- without expecting a good result -- an update panel, and I got what I was expecting.

OK, so that's where it is on this page. I have another .aspx page in this same project in which I am doing the exact same thing -- setting the visible property of a panel within a datalist item template --  and it works just fine. **The only thing different between the two pages is that the page on which it works is a standalone page, i.e. not part of the site.master. The page on which it is not working *is* part of the site.master, residing in a `ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent"`block.** So I've tried doing a `findcontrol` drilling down through the MainContent block to the Datalist ItemTemplate. When I do that, it throws a Null Reference error when it gets to the panel.

I hope I've explained this properly.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: are you using the `ClientIDMode="static"` in the content place holder ?

Comment: @ModarNa I hadn't been, but I added it (<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server">) and it didn't seem to help. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: i`m not sure i got you correctly but for clarification : the masterPage changes every tag id at runtime so you may have to retry findcontrol after you added that fix

Comment: Have you tried to move out your code to a standalone aspx to see if it is really a problem related to your master page? I mean, try it exactly like the other page you say it's working.

Comment: @zed I have thought about that, but was frankly too lazy. I'll jump in on that tomorrow morning after my first pot of coffee.

Comment: Great, that way we may narrow it down.

Comment: @BillNorman I usually do this kind of calls client side, bearing in mind the control id for a server side control is control.ClientID. this way there is no postback and the control is definitely on the page so JavaScript calls should find it... just a thought...

Comment: Having to put this on hold because my SQL server is acting up. Ran Microsoft updates, restarted, and updates failed, and now the SQL server won't come back online. Will come back to this hopefully later today.